# How to make custom godot export template for android on linux?

Tags: android, godot-4, gradle

I want to make custom godot export templates for android to use them instead of official export templates on linux. These templates are intended to not include 3d editor, 3d nodes or advanced gui_templates.

I followed these two links:

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/contributing/development/compiling/compiling_for_android.html

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/contributing/development/compiling/optimizing_for_size.html

I have downloaded godot source code from github, then created custom.py inside the source code folder with these lines of code:

```
disable_3d = "yes"
disable_advanced_gui = "yes"
```

I have also download the requirements for the whole process. that includes scons and android sdk (with these packages cmdline tools, ndk, platform tools, cmake). Regarding python 3.6 is already installed on my operating system (Zorin OS 16).
After that I opened terminal and wrote this command: `export SDK_ROOT=/home/user/Android/Sdk`
Then this command according to documentation: `scons platform=android target=template_release arch=armv7`

However, I got this:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Invalid target platform "android".
The following platforms were detected:

    linuxbsd

Please run SCons again and select a valid platform: platform=<string>
```

Also, I tried what is written in "Setting up the buildsystem" at one of the pages I have linked, but again I got an error.

I wrote this command: `cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=</home/user/Android/Sdk> --licenses`

However, I got this error: `bash: /home/user/Android/Sdk: No such file or directory`

Please help me if there are other alternatives to this process or highlighting what I am missing to able to achieve that correctly.